# Why does GetRange() throws ArgumentException?

Tags: c#

The console says that: System.argument.exception: offset and length were out of bounds for array or count is greater than number of elements from index to the end of source collection.

> at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.GetRange(Int 32 index,Int 32 count)
>   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.sortmerge(List1` given)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {   
        List<int> unsorted = new List<int>();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the size: ");
        int n=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the elements of unsorted array: ");
        for (int a = 0; a < n;a++ )
        {
            unsorted.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));


        }
        Console.WriteLine("The elements of your unsorted list are: ");
        foreach (int item in unsorted)
        {
            Console.Write(item.ToString()+"\t");
        }

        List<int> sorted = sortmerge(unsorted); 
        return;
    } //end of main.

    public static List<int> sortmerge(List<int> given)
    {
        if (given.Count == 1)
            return given;

            List<int> sorted = new List<int>();
            int mid = given.Count / 2;
            List<int> arrlft = new List<int>().GetRange(0,mid);
            List<int> arrryt = new List<int>().GetRange(mid,given.Count/2);
           //dividing phase
            arrlft = sortmerge(arrlft);
            arrryt = sortmerge(arrryt);

            //conquering phase
            int leftptr = 0;
            int rightptr = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < arrryt.Count + arrlft.Count; i++)
            {
                if (leftptr == arrlft.Count)
                {
                    sorted.Add(arrryt[rightptr]);
                    rightptr++;
                }
                else if (rightptr == arrryt.Count)
                {
                    sorted.Add(arrlft[leftptr]);
                }
                else if (arrlft[leftptr] < arrryt[rightptr])
                {
                    sorted.Add(arrlft[leftptr]);
                    leftptr++;
                }
                else
                {
                    sorted.Add(arrryt[rightptr]);
                    rightptr++;
                }
            }   //end of for loop.


            return sorted;


    }


}

}
```

Comment: Ok - sounds like the error message is pretty straight-forward. What's the question?

Comment: You dont need to create a new List from `List.GetRange` since the method already returns a new List.

Comment: `GetRange` will throw an exception if there are not enough elements in the original list to fulfill the request. If you want to take the range (5 of 7 = 5), or the most possible elements that exists (5 of 3 = 3), use the `Take` Linq method, which just takes a limit and doesn't throw an Exception if there are too few elements.

Answer (score 4):

You do not want to call `GetRange` on a new, empty `List` (which is what you are doing here `new List<int>().GetRange(0, mid)`) since the method itself extracts a subset from the given instance, and any subset of empty is always empty.

Try this instead,

```
List<int> arrlft = given.GetRange(0, mid);
List<int> arrryt = given.GetRange(mid, given.Count / 2);
```

You cannot call `GetRange` on an empty list with a positive `index` and `count`. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),

> Throws `ArgumentException` when index and count do not denote a valid range of elements in the List.

Also, if you read the exception message (which you posted), it provides a clue to the problem,

> `System.ArgumentException`, offset and length were out of bounds for array or count is greater than number of elements from index to the end of source collection.